# Button.OnClientClick question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm gonna post some more code to show exactly what I'm trying to do,
I'm adding the button using programming code and not markup but the OnClick won't work (giving the following error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
Button btnopslaan = new Button();
btnopslaan.Text = "Opslaan";
btnopslaan.ID = "btnOpslaan";
btnopslaan.CssClass = ".opslaan";
btnopslaan.Click += new EventHandler(btnopslaanClick);
btnopslaan_arr[btn_count] = btnopslaan;
add_button(btnopslaan);

protected void btnopslaanClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("success");
}
```

I just can't find out why this isn't working.

Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**or** you make it a **postback** call to the server. in your

aspx write:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonOpslaan" Text="opslaan" ></asp:Button>
```

codebehind write this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonOpslaan.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOpslaan_Click);
}

// mind: this method can be private
void buttonOpslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

**or** handle it with the **AutoEventWireUp** (recommended) like:

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" 
    ID="buttonOpslaan" 
    OnClick="buttonOpslaan_Click" 
    Text="opslaan" ></asp:Button>

// mind: this method cannot be private, but has to be protected at least.
protected void buttonOpslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

or do it completely from code behind:

```
// note: buttonOpslaan must have an (autoassigned) ID.
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button buttonOpslaan = new Button();
    buttonOpslaan.Text = "opslaan!";
    buttonOpslaan.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOpslaan_Click);
    form1.Controls.Add(buttonOpslaan);
}

protected void buttonOpslaan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

or handle it clientside with javascript in your ASPX (it will not reach the server)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonOpslaan_Click(){
        alert("test");
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" 
    ID="buttonOpslaan" 
    OnClientClick="buttonOpslaan_Click()"        
    Text="opslaan" ></asp:Button>
```

**Update:** (*by comments*)

if you add the control via an eventhandler (like the `onchange event` of a `dropdownlist`), the control is 'lost' on next postback, or even as soon as the Page is send to the client (due to the stateless (there is no mechanism to maintain the state of application) behaviour and [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) of .Net).

**So simply adding a control once is never going to work.**

That means you have to **rebuild** the control **every time a postback occurs**. My preferred way to do this is store a list/document somewhere that descrbes what controls must be created each time. Possible locations are, from worse to good (IMHO):

- Session
- Viewstate
- Cache
- XML/IO
- Database

After all, you are posting "data" to the server (that represents a control) and you want to save that for further use.

If the controls to be created aren't that complex you could implement a Factory Pattern like a **WebControlFactory** that stores only a few properties in a List or Dictionary, which is read every time to recreate the controls again (and again, and again, and again)

Comment: Can't use aspx couse i use programming code to add the button. I tried the EventHandles but still won't work :/ .

Comment: Tried re-writing the litlle piece of code for the button as you said 'do it completely from code behind' but still, wen I click the button it refreshes the page, clears the whole page but doesn't do what I ask (Tried a test label and on click testlabel.text = "succes" but olso does nothing)

Comment: In what method do you create the button? and what is add_button(btnopslaan); ?

Comment: Got a panel where i put in labels, radiobuttons and some buttons (couse the number of lables etc is not fixed). Method : ddlModel_SelectedIndexChanged -> Dropdownlist.  addbutton(btnopslaan) is the method i use to add my button, I know i used the hard way to do this :P

Comment: I will put the page online so you can have a look what i'm doing exactly

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `OnClick` for server side clicks rather than OnClientClick

Either you can use it inline >

```
<asp:Button id="btnopslaan" runat="server' OnClick="btnopslaanClick" />
```

Or in Code behind >

```
btnopslaan.Click+=new EventHandler(btnopslaanClick);
```

Comment: That's what i tought but when i use it it gives the folowing error : 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible deu to its protection level.'

Answer (score 0):

`btnopslaanClick` should be client side, in the `.aspx` itself have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function btnopslaanClick() {
   alert("success");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't use the aspx becouse I add the button using programming code and not aspx

Comment: @Nico not relevant at all. It doesn't matter how the button is created, if you want to use the `OnClientClick` you need to have the JS code in the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnopslaan.Click+=new EventHandler(btnopslaanClick);

protected void btnopslaanClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Debug.WriteLine("succes");

}
```

Comment: That's what i tought but when i use it it gives the folowing error : 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible deu to its protection level.'